# How to systematically remove columns from dataframe [R]

Tags: r

I have a dataset (df1) that I want to normalize to the averages of another dataset (df2) that both have the same column names. 
Here is an example of what df1 would look like:

```
Rownames Region A Region B Region C
M1           4       5        6
M2           3       4        5
M3           2       5        6
```

However, if the average is below a certain number in df2, say 0.5, I'd like to delete that column in df1. I already have the list of averages from df2 in *avgs*.

Averages of df2:

```
          Region A Region B Region C
Avgs          0.1       3        5
```

So Region A should be deleted for having an avg in df2 of 0.1.

```
Rownames Region B Region C
M1           5        6
M2           4        5
M3           5        6
```

Here's the code I have so far for this purpose:

```
for(i in colNames.df1){
    if(avgs[[i]]<0.5){df1 <- subset(x = df1, select = -i)}
```

I thought this would work, but I get: "invalid argument to unary operator"
regarding the

```
select = -i
```

I'm assuming it's because it's a string, but I'm not sure how to remedy this. Or perhaps there's another approach that I'm not thinking of in doing this without the subset?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but you are missing a round bracket in the example above

Comment: Thanks, edited, but I have it in my original code, so that's not the problem unfortunately :(

Comment: Please provide an example data set and expected outcome

Comment: Try `df1 <- df[, -i]`

Comment: How about `df1<-df1[,!avgs<0.5]`

Comment: Frank P. it gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one step:

```
df1 <- df1[, -which(avgs < 0.5)]
```

This removes the columns (by index) from `df1` for which the corresponding element in `avgs` is less than 0.5.

As @akrun pointed out in a comment, using `which()` will fail if there are no elements of `avgs` with values below 0.5. To remedy this, you could alternatively use

```
df1 <- df1[, !(avgs < 0.5)]
```

When there are values in `avgs` less than 0.5, that will get you the same thing as the previous approach. This approach removes corresponding columns from `df1` where the condition `!(avgs < 0.5)` evaluates to `FALSE`. But unlike the previous approach, if all cases return `TRUE`, no columns are removed.

You are correct that the error you're getting is because `i` is a string. This approach avoids that entirely.

Comment: @akrun: Thanks, I appreciate your input. I added that to the answer.